Why is my React Signals dialog not opening here?
I am trying to control a MUI dialog with a signal, but even with the < p > the value from the signal is not rendered. However, the value of the signal is changed in the console. So if i click the FAB nothing happens.
App.jsx
import Fab from "@mui/material/Fab";
import AddIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Add";
import "./App.css";

import AddItemDialog from "./AddItemDialog";
import { signal } from "@preact/signals-react";

const addItemDialog = signal(false);

function App() {
    console.log("Render App");

    const fabStyle = {
        position: "absolute",
        bottom: 16,
        right: 16,
    };

    function openDialog() {
        addItemDialog.value = true;
    }

    return (
        <>
            <p>{addItemDialog.value}Test</p>
            <AddItemDialog addItemDialog={addItemDialog} />
            <Fab sx={fabStyle} color="primary" onClick={openDialog}>
                <AddIcon />
            </Fab>
        </>
    );
}

export default App;

AddItemDialog.jsx
mport React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Dialog, DialogTitle, DialogContent } from "@mui/material";

export default function AddItemDialog({ addItemDialog }) {
    console.log("Render Dialog");

    const name = useRef();

    function close() {
        addItemDialog.value = false;
    }

    return (
        <Dialog open={addItemDialog.value} onClose={close} fullWidth maxWidth="sm">
            <DialogTitle>Add Item</DialogTitle>
            <DialogContent>
                <input type="text" ref={name} />
            </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
    );
}

Preview of Website
Replacing the signal to useState would work, but the whole app rerenders after changing
Edit:
I got it to work by putting both compenents into another one and using the state there, but still why doesn't it work with the signal?

This doesn't work as you haven't fully followed the getting started instructions: https://github.com/preactjs/signals/tree/main/packages/react#react-integration
As of v2, you need to use the Babel plugin or the useSignals() hook.
import { signal } from "@preact/signals-react";
import { useSignals } from "@preact/signals-react/runtime";

const addItemDialog = signal(false);

function App() {
    useSignals();
    //...
}

Please ignore that other user, they are entirely misinformed. Signals do trigger React component re-renders, without this, they'd be rather useless.
Edit: The video you linked to was using Signals v1, which had some edge cases and the ire of the React core team, so we changed it. It's not as succinct, but we deemed this to be a better option than to make signals exclusive to Preact users

Ohh okay thanks! Would you recommend using the barbel plugin or the useSignals() hook? Do I need to install anything else other than the tutorial here? It works for me with the useSignals() hook, but although I followed the Barbel installation guide, it doesn't work without it. https://github.com/preactjs/signals/blob/main/packages/react-transform/README.md

It depends on your needs really. The Babel plugin is nice as it lets you skip having to think about useSignals(), which subscribes a component to any signals accessed inside. However, not all tools use Babel and it could be unfeasible to add it to your tooling setup. If you're struggling to get Babel working with your tooling, we'd need to know which build tool you're using.
